# Return columns when certain value is present in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to generate a column 'd', it contains column variable name where the value is equal to 1.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1],'b':[1,1,np.nan],'c':[1,1,1]})
```

Expected output:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1],'b':[1,1,np.nan],'c':[1,1,1],'d':['a;b;c','b;c','a;c']})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! May I ask what have you tried? If you have, please update it in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `DataFrame.apply` on rows

```py
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda row: ';'.join(row.index[row.eq(1)]), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   a    b  c      d
0  1  1.0  1  a;b;c
1  0  1.0  1    b;c
2  1  NaN  1    a;c
```

Or `mask` the column header dataframe

```py
df['d'] = (pd.DataFrame([df().columns]*len(df), columns=df.columns)[df.eq(1)]
           .apply(lambda row: ';'.join(row.dropna()), axis=1))
```